# php "||" assignment logic compared to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variable-assignment

I was testing Heredoc and || functionality

```
function test()
{
    $obj = [(object)['col1'=>'val1'],
            (object)['col2'=>'val2'],
            (object)['col3'=>'val3']];
    $output = '';
$mystring = <<<EOT
a non empty string
EOT;

    foreach($obj as $prop)
    {
        foreach($prop as $i)
        {
            $output .= <<<EOT
            <div style='background-color:lightblue'> 
            \$head  : {gettype($i)} 
            </div>
EOT;
        }
    }
    $out =  $output || $mystring || 'couldn\'t find something valuable';
    echo $out;
}
test();
```

I get the output of

> 1

which represents a Boolean true.
I had it output the contents of $mystring at one point by putting the logic in brackets eg

```
echo ($output || $mystring);
```

and it used to output:

> a non empty string

It stopped working straight after and I am not sure what change broke it.

In javascript:

```js
    function test()
    {
    
        var obj = [{'col1':'val1'},
                {'col2':'val2'},
                {'col3':'val3'}];
        var output = '';
        var mystring ="a non empty string";
    
        for(var prop in obj)
        {
            for(var i in prop)
            {
                output += 
                "<div style='background-color:lightblue'>" +
                    i + " : " + typeof prop[i] +
                    "</div>";
            }
        }
        out =  output || mystring || 'couldn\'t find something valuable';
        document.write(out);
        console.log("outputting \n\t" + out);
    }
    test();
```

It is slightly different from the php in terms of logic but the || during assignment works as expected. I get

> 0 : string
>
> 0 : string
>
> 0 : string

for the code above. If comment out the inner for loop like so

```
for(var prop in obj)
{
    /*for(var i in prop)
    {
        output += 
        "<div style='background-color:lightblue'>" +
        i + " : " + typeof prop[i] +
        "</div>";
    }*/
}
```

I get the contents of "mystring" which is

> a non empty string

and if I then change mystring to an empty string like so

```
mystring = ""; //"a non empty string";
```

I get

> couldn't find something valuable

How does php's "||" during assignment work ?
Can someone explain it?

Comment: please fix your code formatting. `function test() { ` and `} test()` is unformatted.

Comment: @noc2spamツ thanks. fixed it just before I read your comment.XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign a conditional expression in php you always get a boolean (that is, strictly `true` or `false`), it does not work as in javascript where the "truthy" value gets assigned, so in PHP

```
$a = "";
$b = 42;
$c = ($a || $b); // == true
```

While in javascript

```
var a = "";
var b = 42;
var c = (a || b); // == 42
```

and this is, sadly, by language design.

As @billyonecas reports, it is also in the comments to the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php#77411

To obtain a similar behaviour in PHP, we must do something like:

```
$a = "";
$b = 42;
$c = ($a ?: $b); // newer php version
$c = ($a ? $a : $b); // older php version
```

if you need to concatenate expression, use parethesis:

```
$c = ($a ? $a : ($b ? $b : "not found"));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php#77411 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Ok. but i did get it to work temporarily at one point by putting brackets around it. why could that be?

Comment: I really do not know, it just **couldn't be** as far as I know.

Comment: I meant reproduce the result I got when using ||. but thanks. found that method with @KyleK in his comment section. it does allow the same logic though

Comment: Only the inside parenthesis is needed in the nested ternary expression, assignation has not the precedence. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Yes, that is true, but to me it feels more clear by explicitely using parenthesis :)

Answer (score 1):

With PHP, you can use `?:`

```
$out =  $output ?: $mystring;
```

Or in older versions of PHP:

```
$out =  $output ? $output : $mystring;
```

You can also use `empty()` to get a more explicit code:

```
$out =  empty($output) ? $mystring : $output;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Note: these ternary expressions are equivalent to if-else:

```
if(empty($output))
{
    $out = $mystring;
}
else
{
    $out = $output;
}
```

With nested ternary, add parentheses, as the default precedence is:

```
$out =  $output ? $output : $mystring ? $mystring : 'default';
```

This is:

```
$out =  ($output ? $output : $mystring) ? $mystring : 'default';
```

So you must do:

```
$out =  $output ? $output : ($mystring ? $mystring : 'default');
```

Comment: you say empty() gets more explicit code. like the kind of output you would get form var_dump() or json_encode()? <-(more descriptive easier to read)

Comment: I tried    $out =  $output? $output : $mystring ? $mystring :  'couldnt find something valuable'; just before I read your post. I like the newer php version you have enlightened me to. I got the content of $mystring though(a non empty string) instead of the content of $output. not sure why

Comment: Just add the parentheses: `$out = $output ? $output : ($mystring ? $mystring : 'couldnt find something valuable');` and I do not understand your first comment.

Comment: about my first comment : sorry was just asking if what the output of empty() looks like but I will look it up

Comment: Done, for functions please see the doc, empty return true or false, it why it is more explicit to use it in a condition.